# Why is WebClient DownloadString returning \r\n?

Tags: xml, rest, serialization

I am trying to Deserialize it and I think all the \r\n everywhere is causing a problem.

Any idea what this is about ?

```
    //   static string baseUrl = "http://service.leads360.com/ClientService.asmx/GetLastModifiedLead?username=xxx&password=xxx";

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
        //    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
         //   webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string result = webClient.DownloadString(baseUrl);
            return result;
        }

 public static Stream ToStream(this string @this)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(@this);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}

public static T ParseXML<T>(this string @this) where T : class
{
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(@this.Trim().ToStream(), new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document });
    return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader) as T;
}
```

Comment: Download string doesn't manipulate the content. This must be present in the content which is being downloaded. simply replace them by `string.empty`.

Comment: Ok. Ill try that. Strange I didn't find anyone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was a dummy and calling the wrong service so the problem was just trying to serialize the object.. I saw the \r\n in the debugger and thought that was the cause